# How can I save my Cedar Bonsai?

Tags: trees, bonsai, dryness

[image: cedar drying]

This is the current state of my baby bonsai. I live in Istanbul. I put this in front of my window facing north. This is a 3 years old bonsai grew from the seed. This issue started 3 weeks ago, I started watering more but didn't help.

in March I pruned the roots, and gave a little vermicompost.

Do you think that caused to this? I need help asap.

Comment: I am afraid this tree looks dead, my guess is it dried up due to not enough water or too dry air?

Comment: I'm sorry to say I agree - it's beyond resurrection and is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thirding the above answers. If all the leaves are dry and brown like that, you've lost the plant. Sorry.

Cedars do best with nutrient-rich, evenly moist but well-draining soil. They're vulnerable to drought stress and if the soil is too dry the needles can easily parch in seasons with insufficient humidity. Wild cedars will grow on the damp side of a mountain range, with the rain shadow left to more drought-tolerant pines. Your best bet is likely to be looking up specifics about your individual species of cedar, and giving it conditions as close to the ones in its native range as you can.

Hope this helps with your next attempt.

Comment: I found some green leafs left in two trenches. I pruned the brown trenches and juat left ones that has some green leafs. I hope I can resurrect from this point. Wish my tree luck.